# How to make Tkinter message expand when I resize the window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get a tkinter message widget to make the words move when I resize the window. Right now, the window is a small block, and the line of text is an ugly block. How can I make it expand. This is the code I have.

```
root = Tk()
Message(text="This is a Tkinter message widget. Pretty exiting, huh? I enjoy Tkinter. It is very simple.").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I hope you understand my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the width of the Message text when you resize the window.  As far as I know, there is no way to tell the Message widget do that automatically, so you're stuck with using a callback:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Message

root = Tk()
m = Message(text="This is a Tkinter message widget. Pretty exiting, huh? I enjoy Tkinter. It is very simple.")
m.pack(expand=True, fill='x')
m.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: m.configure(width=e.width-10))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is `e` in your example? My code attempted to draw the whole window to fit the screen.