# Example where lambdas are very useful in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming, lambda

I met `lambda` expressions in `Python`. I have seen already many easy examples (including examples on SE) where lambda expressions produce functions like adders of whatever but I can't see the real usefulness of them yet, e.g. some example where it would be pain to write the same peace of code without lambdas.

Could you show something for text processing where you would use lambda expressions and it would be hard to avoid lambda expressions? But something that is practical (not mathematical game).

Comment: rewrite some of your own imperative code the functional way this time. Perhaps then you'll see why and when lambdas are useful ;-)

Comment: List comprehensions are not, strictly speaking, a replacement for lambdas. They're more a replacement for the `map` and `filter` functions. Admittedly, lambdas are often used with `map` and `filter`.

Comment: What is the point of saying "hard to avoid"?  Lambdas are useful when they allow multiple lines of function definition to be replaced with a single, more readable line. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363390/how-to-make-tkinter-message-expand-when-i-resize-the-window/8364895#8364895 wouldn't have been "hard" to write without lambda, but it's certainly more compact and easier with it.

Comment: @Dave The answer I like so far is from bpgergo because it shows that lambdas way is much better.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy: that's ridiculous - As evidenced in the answers below, lambdas are used in many places that have nothing to do with (and certainly can't be replaced by) list comprehensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IN this case, it would have been painful to write out all lambda expressions as separate function.

What does this code does in briefly? Converts a custom excel table into insert statements for a custom database table. There is mapping between the excel table fields and the database fields and also there is a mapping between excel table fields and functions to be applied on the excel table value, before it gets inserted to the db. You do not really want to define a separate function for every field.

```
map_func = { 'ID' : lambda x : 'mig_farm_seq.nextval',
             'ENTERPRISE_NAME' : wrap_str,
             'TAX_NUMBER' : wrap_str,
             'FAMILY_NAME' : lambda x : wrap_str(x.split()[0]),
             'GIVEN_NAME' : lambda x : wrap_str(x.split()[1]),
             'ENTERPRISE_REGISTRATION_NUMBER' : wrap_str,
             'PREMISE_NAME' : wrap_str,
             'HOUSE_ID' : wrap_str,
             'POSTAL_CODE' : wrap_str,
             'PHONE_NUMBER_1' : lambda x : wrap_str(get_phone_number(x, True)),
             'PHONE_NUMBER_2' : lambda x : wrap_str(get_phone_number(x, False)),
             'FAX_NUMBER' : lambda x : wrap_str(x.replace(' ', '')),
             'BANK_IDENTIFIER' : lambda x : wrap_str(x.replace(' ', '').replace('-', '')[:3]),
             'BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER' : lambda x : wrap_str(x.replace(' ', '').replace('-', '')),
             'NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES' : wrap_null,
             'SETTLEMENT_NUMBER' : wrap_null,
             'REGISTRATION_NUMBER' : lambda x : insert_reg_number % x,
             'GENDER' : wrap_str,
             'ACTIVITY' : lambda x : '0',
             'REG_HOLDER_ACTIVITY' : lambda x : '0',
             'PROCESSED_BY_JOB' : lambda x : '0'
         }
```

source: http://pastebin.com/MxEPBMaZ

Comment: I have used this same design pattern many times in real-world code. So +1 for good example.

Comment: @bpgergo This is good example. I'm thinking about accepting, but will wait for approx. a day yet.

Comment: +1 - good example. I've also used this pattern (or one very similar to it) a number of times.

Answer (score 4):

One place I use them often: the `key` function of the `sort` and `sorted` functions:

```
>>> person = lambda name, age: { "name": name, "age": age }
>>> people = [ person("Joe", 61), person("Jane", 52) ]
>>> people.sort(key=lambda person: person["age"])
```

This will sort the list of people by their age.

Another place I use lambdas is with `re.sub`:

```
>>> re.sub("0x([0-9a-f]+)", lambda match: "0x" + match.group(1).upper(), "0xfa")
'0xFA'
```

Comment: For sort sort keys, using `operator.*getter()` is often clearer/faster/shorter/better. This could be replaced by `people.sort(key=operator.itemgetter("age"))`.

Comment: Yes, for simple cases it's possible to use the `operator` module… But IMO it's reasonable to use a lambda there, and there are cases where the `operator` is insufficient (just for ex, if you wanted to sort by (last name, first name): `people.sort(key=lambda p: (p["last_name"], p["first_name"])`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of suggesting anything out here I would recommend to visit the lib directory of your Python Installation and grep for `lambda`. You will get enough examples to satisfy your appetite.

Comment: A very good suggestion. To this I would add the following: "try to rewrite the code using lambda constructs into code that doesn't use them, and then compare the two versions. Perhaps this will help you see the usefulness (or uselessnes) of lambdas on a case-by-case basis".

Comment: @Abhijit Please, be more specific. Many files have no lambdas or only few.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've asked about text processing, take a look at [this](http://www.valuedlessons.com/2008/02/pysec-monadic-combinatoric-parsing-in.html) example (and [this one](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) is similar).

Closures are almost always easier to handle than objects (since the environment is captured implicitly), but to those thinking in terms of OOP it is not that obvious. I'd recommend trying to learn at least one decent functional language (lambdas in python are too limited), and this way you'll understand how to apply those techniques efficiently in languages like Python.

Answer (score 0):

They are useful when you need a short function to compare two items or perform some other operation, and this will be passed as an argument, and there is no need for the function to have a name because it is only used as an argument.

They are useful when the function, written as a lambda, is shorter than the `def` line you would ordinarily use to name it and the `return` you would use at the end.

They are useful when you want to partially apply a function -- that is you have a function that you need to pass somewhere else, and want to provide some or all of the arguments to the passed function without actually calling it. Lamdda lets you do this without having to define and name a separate function for each variation you need.

Comment: This is what I already know, but some example that do something that shows that lambdas are indispensable is what I'm asking. And the example should do something useful (not just mathematical playing)

Comment: They are not indispensable; after all, they are just a function, and you can write functions all day without lambda. Lambda functions are merely very convenient, and sometimes more readable.

Comment: maybe `indispensable` is a strong word. I haven't seen the example yet, where I would say: "this would be terrible to do without lambda expressions."

Comment: @xralf, A direct replacement for lambda is a class with a number of fields to store the captured environment and a single method `run`. But: you'll have to store the environment manually (i.e., perform a lambda lifting on your own), and there'll be too much of a boilerplate code. Think of lambda functions as syntax sugar.

Answer (score 0):

All of my Django projects include 2 strings (settings.py):

```
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
_rel = lambda x: os.path.join(DIRNAME, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

One case where they're actually useful:

Say you're using PyQt, which allows you to connect signals to other slots (methods). Sometimes, I have the need to rather just execute a certain action, rather than write a function, so all I need is a throwaway function.

```
obj.signal.connect(lambda: doFoo(bar))
```

Of course, that is contrasted with:

```
def doBoo():
    return doFoo(bar)
obj.signal.connect(doBoo)
```

.. Much cleaner the former way.